# Does the position of capacitors create ripple voltage?

Tags: esp32, ripple, brownout

I'm designing a multi-sensor board controlled by an ESP32-Pico-D4. I did tests with version 3 being able to programm it, but I decided to make it smaller by removing the USB chip (just leave pins for programming) and adding more pins.  V4 has a continous brownout voltage error and keeps rebooting.

I asked in a youtube stream, and they said "it might be ripple voltage," so I checked my new design and I moved the capacitor's connection from connected to the main source to a group of capacitors connected at some point to that line. Could that be the reason?

[image]

Comment: Ripple voltage of what? We can't analyze from the schematics if something called "ripple voltage" is the source of your reboots. It may be your power source, faulty component or whatever.

Comment: What does the layout look like?  Bypass capacitors belong as close as physically possible to the consumer.

Comment: Did it solve the problem?

Comment: @Justme I can't confirm ripple voltage in the power of ESP32 as I don't have an oscilloscope, but I changed components, USB cable, USB ports, PC.
The esp32 still rebooting after brownout error, but the voltage in my multimeter is constant.

Comment: Show the difference in the connections. What did you remove, where were they connected, and how are the pins now connected as they are unused and it may not be correct to leave something floating.